# remove list item in from nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested diciotnary that contains lists. I want to remove a list item if it is the string 'maybe'. I tried with a one liner below but it isnt removing the 'maybe' value. Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you!

```
# my dictionary 
d =  {'x':{'a':['yes', 'no', 'maybe'], 'b': ['yellow', 'maybe']}, 'y':{'a': ['sometimes', 'maybe'], 'c':['no']}}#, 'fop':{'a':0.145, 'b': numpy.nan, 'c':0.485}}


# my attempt
{ k: {a: b for a, b in v.items() if b != 'maybe'} for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: `b` is a list, not a string. You're not iterating over the list elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you b is a list an not the elements of that list, so you have to find the string within that list.

```py
{ k: {a: [bb for bb in b if bb != 'maybe' ] for a, b in v.items() } for k, v in d.items()}
```

if you want to do that with list comprehensions